# in Parse.com, how to use query.includeKey in PFQueryTableViewController with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to populate a table using PFQueryTableViewController.
I want to use data from two class, which is `Places` and `Details`.

In `Places`, I have two column, which is `placeText` as `string`, and `pointerToDetails` as pointer.

In `Details`, I have one column, which is `detailText`.

I want to show the `placeText` and `detailText` in the same `CustomCell` which I already defined as `PFTableViewCell`.

Unfortunately, after I run the code, I only got the `placeText` inside the `CustomCell`.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
    }

    // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Places")
        query.includeKey("pointerToDetails")
        return query
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as CustomTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        }

        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        cell.name.text = object["placeText"] as String!
        cell.detail.text = object["detailText"] as String!

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I got an inspiration from @deadbeef (see answer 1), here is the solution I got :

1. `query.includeKey("pointerToDetails")` is querying an object which can be accessed via `object["pointerToDetails"]`.
2. to extract data from column `detailText` which already included in `object["pointerToDetails"]`, just do this :

---

```
if let pointer = object["pointerToDetails"] as? PFObject {
     cell.detail.text = object["detailText"] as String!
}
```

---

here is the whole code :

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
    }

    // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Places")
        query.includeKey("pointerToDetails")
        return query
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as CustomTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        }

        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        cell.name.text = object["placeText"] as String!
        if let pointer = object["pointerToDetails"] as? PFObject {
            cell.detail.text = object["detailText"] as String!
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `detailtext` property will not be included in your object as the `includeKey()` might suggest, but the `Details` object pointed by `pointerToDetails` will be queried along with you `Places` object.

So in order to get the value of `detailText`, you have to go through the pointer. In other words, try this :

```
cell.name.text = object["placeText"] as String!
cell.detail.text = object["pointerToDetails"]["detailText"] as String!
```

Comment: thanks for your idea. Actually, yours is not working with me. But I found this is working. you can see my answer above.  `if let pointer = object["pointerToDetails"] as? PFObject {
     cell.detail.text = object["detailText"] as String!
}`

Comment: Yeah that looks more swift like. Sorry I actually don't know swift, I was just guessing the syntax ^^